# Invoke a constructor with the help of typeof

Tags: javascript

I'm attemping a bit of a dance to get some classical polymorphism in javascript; something like

```
function Inherit(base, sub) {
   var baseType = typeof base;
   sub.prototype = new baseType();
}
```

Anyone have a clue as to how to do this without having to new up base prior to passing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typeof` operator will always return a `string` so that is pretty much off the table. You should be able to do something like this. Although I don't really see how this adds value to the JavaScript type system.

```
function Base() {

}

function Sub() {

}

function Inherit(base, sub) {
   sub.prototype = new base();
}

Inherit(Base, Sub);
```

Comment: Im trying more or less to push the ceremony down a level instead of prototyping all over the code. I had something very similar to what you have there originally but was being screamed at that base is not a constructor. Perhaps the real answer is having co workers shake the classical paradigm of inheritance and learn to love prototyping.. Thanks chaose.

Comment: @Gnostus - Personally I love the simplicity of the prototype model. With JavaScript I can skip a whole bunch of type ceremony you see in C# or Java. Although it did take me a while to get used to it.

Comment: Yea I develop in C# all day but recently got switched to a web based project and went from thinking javascript was a cutesy browser language to looking into making a linux desktop app with it :D! I eventually get to hand this over to a couple other C# developers so I figured keeping it as aesthetically classical as possible without losing the awesomeness that is Functional<->Prototyped would be the best route.